# Notepad++ search result window gone forever - All discussed tricks don't work

Tags: notepad++, search, window

I lost my "search result window" in Notepad++. (Using Windows 7 64 Bit, running Notepad++ 7.5.9 32 Bit) - I tried the following:

- Alt+Space / Move Window (not working)
- Press F7 to activate "search result window" and try Alt+Space trick again  (not working)
- Analyse config.xml in App-Data for suspicious window coordinates  (not working)
- Delete AppData\Notepad++  (not working)
- Delete AppData\Notepad++, uninstall Notepad++ and install latest version of Notepad++ (not working)
- Uninstall Notepad++ and install 7.4.xx Version of Notepad++ (not working)

I need this window to copy/paste search results based on regex-search.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: if it helps, F7 does nothing for me in Npp, nor does selecting `Search -> Search Results Window` after I've entered a regex with multiple results, and clicked Find Next once. Seems like a feature regression.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the [Portable Apps](https://portableapps.com) version of NP++ and I have no problems. I've not used the search results window before, so the interface may have changed.

By itself <kbd>F7</kbd> doesn't do anything until you click on `Find All in Current Document`.

[image: NP++ Find]

Now the search results window appears. If it's closed with the <kbd>x</kbd> button, then <kbd>F7</kbd> will reopen it.

I would find it surprising if the installed version behaves differently, as I use a lot of PortableApps and have never noticed functional differences.

The PortableApps version of NP++ is currently v7.5.8, and I tested on Win10/1803.

Comment: That works for me. Op?

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to me the search result window of Notepad++ was hiding behind Windows Task Bar.

You can temporary set Task Bar to dock on the left or right of your computer screen.

Run search in notepad++, you will find the result window near the bottom of screen.

Move it out from bottom of screen and dock it inside notepad++. Then set task bar back to bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found out on Windows 10: Keep NotePad++ open, find tab of Search on the upper layer-> Search Results Window

Answer (score 0):

I renamed np config file. (found in c:\Users\xxxMyName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml)
closed np
when re opening, the search results worked as expected

(suggested in https://www.technipages.com/fix-notepad-not-showing-search-results)

Answer (score -1):

Restore search window in PN2

Remove key ‘Interface Settings’ and subkeys using regedit at

Computer\HKEY_USERS\SOFTWARE\Echo Software\PN2\

Comment: Your answer does not apply to Notepad++. Notepadd++ is not a product of "Echo Software".